# How to integrate Pinterest in ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, pinterest

I want to integrate **pinterest** in my application. i want to add button of pinterest in my app through which i can upload image on pinterest I refer [their Developers site](http://developers.pinterest.com/) but it doesnt help me.

I include SDK and tried their code but it doesnt work for me.

```
  #import <Pinterest/Pinterest.h>

UIButton* pinItButton = [Pinterest pinItButton];
    [pinItButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(pinIt:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:pinItButton];

 - (void)pinIt:(id)sender
    {
        [_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:@"http://placekitten.com/500/400"
                                sourceURL:@"http://placekitten.com"
                              description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
    }
```

please any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I dont understand whats your actual problem but here i provide some easy step to integrate pinterest to your app

**step : 1** Register for a Client ID from [here](http://developers.pinterest.com/manage/)

**step : 2** Download the SDK from [here](https://pinterest-ota-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/Pinterest.embeddedframework.zip) and drag and drop into your project.

**step : 3** You will then need to add a URL type to support opening your app from the Pinterest app , so add URL type to your plist file

```
Example if your client id is 18571937652947:
pin18571937652947 is the URL Scheme you need to support.
```

**step : 4** To use the Pinterest framework you will need to import it into your file.

```
 #import <Pinterest/Pinterest.h>
```

and declare its object in your .h file

```
 Pinterest *pinterest
```

**step : 5** initialise Pinterest object

```
 pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:@"your app client id"]
```

**step : 6** To use the standard PinIt Button in a view add it as so:

```
 UIButton* pinItButton = [Pinterest pinItButton];
    [pinItButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(pinIt:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:pinItButton];
```

**step : 7** You will need to handle the action an example of this is below:

```
- (void)pinIt:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *imageURL     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com/500/400"];
    NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"];


    [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL
                           sourceURL:sourceURL
                         description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
}
```

**Note** : pinterest app should be installed in your device otherwise this code redirect to itunes to download pinterest app

Comment: Similar directons on Pinterest website can be found here too: http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/

Comment: Ya but there are some point missing in doc. Like initialization of pinterest object.

Comment: @pratikbhiyani can we redirect app to pinterest website in browser instead of pinterest application?

Comment: @pratikbhiyani, so, I can't share via my app, only with pinterest app help? oh...

Comment: @pratikbhiyani  where  place on application pin18571937652947 is the URL Scheme you need to support. i am new please help.

Comment: you need to set it in .plist file

Comment: Download the SDK from here and drag and drop into your project. its give error nothing to download here??????????what to do

Comment: using thi surl:- NSURL *imageURL     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com/500/400"];
    NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"]; nothing happend its not open pintrest

Comment: its give error canOpenURL: failed for URL: "pinit://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme pinit"